# What's the most efficient approach to follow when inject dispatch into components which will call the actions?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Connect it directly into these components or do it in a parent component and pass down the props. It seems more optimal the last one, you just create a connect instance. What do you think?

Here an example:

1. Inject in child components

   ```
   const MenuIcon = connect()(({
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <IconButton onClick={ () => dispatch(reverseLeftMenu())} touch>
       <ImageDehaze />
     </IconButton>
   ))

   const CreateIcon = connect()(({
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(reverseCreateMenu())} touch>
       <ContentAdd />
     </IconButton>
   ))

   const ClientIcons = connect()(({
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <div>
       <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(reverseFavouriteMenu())}>
         <ActionFavorite/>
       </IconButton>
       <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(reverseCartMenu())}>
         <ActionShoppingCart/>
       </IconButton>
     </div>
   ))

   const RightIcons = ({
     isAdmin
   }) => ( isAdmin ? 
     <CreateIcon/>
      : 
     <ClientIcons/>
   )

   const Header = ({
     isAdmin = false
   }) => (
     <Toolbar style={style.bar}>
       <ToolbarGroup float="left" firstChild>
         <MenuIcon/>
       </ToolbarGroup>
       <ToolbarTitle text="TUDELARTE"/>
       <ToolbarGroup float="right" lastChild>
         <RightIcons isAdmin={isAdmin}/>
       </ToolbarGroup>
     </Toolbar>
   )

   Header.propTypes = {
     isAdmin: React.PropTypes.bool
   }

   export default Header
   ```
2. Connect in parent component (Header)

   ```
   const MenuIcon = ({
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <IconButton onClick={ () => dispatch(reverseLeftMenu())} touch>
       <ImageDehaze />
     </IconButton>
   )

   const CreateIcon = ({
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(reverseCreateMenu())} touch>
       <ContentAdd />
     </IconButton>
   )

   const ClientIcons = ({
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <div>
       <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(reverseFavouriteMenu())}>
         <ActionFavorite/>
       </IconButton>  
       <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(reverseCartMenu())}>
         <ActionShoppingCart/>
       </IconButton>
     </div>
   )

   const RightIcons = ({
     isAdmin,
     dispatch
   }) => ( isAdmin ? 
     <CreateIcon dispatch={dispatch}/>
      : 
     <ClientIcons dispatch={dispatch}/>
   )

   const Header = ({
     isAdmin = false,
     dispatch
   }) => (
     <Toolbar style={style.bar}>
       <ToolbarGroup float="left" firstChild>
         <MenuIcon dispatch={dispatch}/>
       </ToolbarGroup>
       <ToolbarTitle text="TUDELARTE"/>
       <ToolbarGroup float="right" lastChild>
         <RightIcons dispatch={dispatch} isAdmin={isAdmin}/>
       </ToolbarGroup>
     </Toolbar>
   )

   Header.propTypes = {
     isAdmin: React.PropTypes.bool
   }

   export default connect()(Header)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very opinion based answer, as it might not be the most efficient way, but i would definitively prefer the second way. I don't see the need here to connect your Components just to gain access to the dispatch functionality. Passing the functionality as a prop also gives your code a much higher reusability, as the parent Component now has the power of controlling child Components, by passing over functionality as props.

I would also not inject the full dispatch, but maybe only the already bound actions with [mapDispatchToProps](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples).

It would look something like this (untested code!):

```
import * as MenuActionCreators from './MenuActionCreators';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux;'


const MenuIcon = ({
    onClickAction
    }) => (
    <IconButton onClick={onClickAction} touch>
        <ImageDehaze />
    </IconButton>
)

const CreateIcon = ({
    onClickAction
    }) => (
    <IconButton onClick={onClickAction} touch>
        <ContentAdd />
    </IconButton>
)

const ClientIcons = ({
    menuActions
    }) => (
    <div>
        <IconButton onClick={menuActions.reverseFavouriteMenu}>
            <ActionFavorite/>
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={menuActions.reverseCartMenu}>
            <ActionShoppingCart/>
        </IconButton>
    </div>
)

const RightIcons = ({
    isAdmin,
    menuActions
    }) => ( isAdmin ?
        <CreateIcon onClickAction={menuActions.reverseCreateMenu}/>
        :
        <ClientIcons menuActions={menuActions}/>
)

const Header = ({
    isAdmin = false,
    menuActions
    }) => (
    <Toolbar style={style.bar}>
        <ToolbarGroup float="left" firstChild>
            <MenuIcon onClickAction={menuActions.reverseLeftMenu}/>
        </ToolbarGroup>
        <ToolbarTitle text="TUDELARTE"/>
        <ToolbarGroup float="right" lastChild>
            <RightIcons menuActions={menuActions} isAdmin={isAdmin}/>
        </ToolbarGroup>
    </Toolbar>
)

Header.propTypes = {
    isAdmin: React.PropTypes.bool,
    menuActions: React.PropTypes.object,
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    // You should not return the full state, but only the parts of it you need
    return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        menuActions: bindActionCreators(MenuActionCreators, dispatch),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: If pass mapStateToPros as null, it doesnt connect to the store, does it?

Comment: @NorberS.M Good catch, wasn't able to test it, so i used the mapStateToProps approach here

Comment: I updated my answer, as this might not be the most efficient way, but more a suggestion on how I would do it.